# iPhone Configuration profiles and Appstore

Tags: iphone, configuration-files, appstore-approval, profiles

To satisfy some requirements in my app, I am planning to use iPhone configuration profiles (generated using iPCU). My questions - Can we deploy an app in AppStore that uses Configuration profiles?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using iPhone configuration profiles can only be used for apps that you write for internal (enterprise) distribution (not on the AppStore).

So unfortunately the answer is no!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install AppStore App using MDM. I tried it and it is working fine. Once you get registered in Apple enterprise developer program, you can checkout the MDM Documentation which clearly demonstrates the way to install AppStore Apps with their APP ID. See the link in this discussion for further details: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5133358